# No elements in Preference Structure

Tags: java, android, xml, structure, preferences

I'm trying to create a `setting.xml` Preferences in XML folder of my Project.
i create a file named `settings.xml` in res/xml and used Preference for Resource Type,
But I can't add any elements.
If I choose other elements in first step, I still can't see It's settings via structure
What should i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: is the space between x and ml just made by You here or did You really Name the Folder and file like that? I´m just wondering because everytime You wrote it here, it has a space

Comment: @Opiatefuchs No it's ok there :))

Comment: :) ok, sorry for this question, I´ve seen to many Errors like this ;) . Could You post the XML?